# Is it possible to trigger a function when a user tries to drag and drop onto a cell border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there any way to trigger a function when a user attempts to drag and drop onto a cell border?

Ultimately, I would like to be able to create a feature that would insert a new column or row when a user tries to drop a block onto a border. Is this even possible? How might I go about doing this?

[image]

Here is a minimal reproducable example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jado66/tab3yeL1/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <style>
    .cell {width:50px;height:50px;}
    .gate {width:50px;height:50px;cursor: move;}
    #blockTable td:hover{background: #dedede;}
    #blockTable {
        border-spacing: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #dedede;
    }
    #newColCanvas{
        border-spacing: 5px;
    }
    #newRowCanvas{
        border-spacing: 5px;
    }
    #newColNRowCanvas{
        border-spacing: 5px;
    }
    .gate:hover{
        transform: scale(1.05);
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
    }
    .droppable{background:  #dedede; border: 1px dotted grey;}
    #blockTable tbody { height:300px; overflow-y:auto;  }
    <body>
    </style>
    
        <table style="border-spacing: 5px;">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <div class = "gate" style="background-color: rgb(93, 151, 75); border: 1px solid black;"  
                            ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="1" draggable="true" >
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <div class = "gate" style="background-color: rgb(207, 233, 94); border: 1px solid black;"  
                            ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="2"  draggable="true" >
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <table id="blockTable" >
            <tr >
                <td id="cellToClone"> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
                <td> <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="toggleBorder(event)" ondragenter="toggleBorder(event)"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
    <script>
    
    function dragStart(evt)
    {
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text",evt.target.id);
    }
    
    function drop(evt)
    {
        evt.target.classList.toggle("droppable");
        evt.preventDefault();
        var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        evt.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    
    function toggleBorder(evt){
        evt.target.classList.toggle("droppable");
    }
    
    function allowDrop(ob)
    {
        ob.preventDefault();
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your border would be a drop target. When the mouse hovers it, it does the logic to insert a new column and remove itself. When the mouse leave the new column, this one removes itself and puts back a border in its place

Comment: Makes sense in theory, but I'm not sure how to access the borders. I have a basic table <table> <tr> <td> and divs with "ondrop" and "ondragover" events. Would I add similar events to <table>, <tr>, <td> or would I need to format my table another way to provide access to the border elements?

Comment: Can you provide a basic snippet of code which shows how you have things set up?

Comment: I've added a JS Fiddle with an MRE of my code